# Problems creating a new node

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to overload the + operator for a class Poly, so that in main.cpp I can just add to Poly's together. The way I'm trying to do this is to:

1. compare left side **expnt** with right side **expnt**
2. create a new node in *Poly temp* with the new found values (explained in the comments)
3. and then return the new Poly to main.cpp to be stored in the pList[ ] array.

For some reason the new node will be created but the pointer to the node gets lost so main.cpp can't access *temp*. Where am I going wrong?

```
// class Poly header file
class Poly {
private:
// DATA MEMBERS
struct Node
{
    double coEf;
    int expnt;
    Node* next;
};

Node* first;
.
.
.
}

// class poly definition file
// Private function
Poly::Node* Poly::get_node( const double num1, const int num2, Node* link)
{
    Node *temp;

    temp = new Node;
    temp -> coEf = num1;
    temp -> expnt = num2;
    temp -> next = link;
    return temp;
}


Poly Poly::operator + ( Poly source)
{
    Node* p1 = first;
    Node* p2 = source.first;
    Node* last;
    Poly temp;
    Node* pt = temp.first;

    // If the left side Poly is empty then just return the right side Poly.
    if(first==NULL)
    {
        Poly(source);
    }
    // If the left side Poly's first exponent is equal to the right side Poly's
    // exponent, then create a node for Poly temp with the following values:
        // expnt = (because the expnt's are equal it doesn't matter which one) (int)
        // coEf = both left side and right side's coEf's added together (double)
        // next = NULL (because it's the end of temp's list)
    if( p1 -> expnt == p2 -> expnt)
    {
        pt = get_node( (( p1 -> coEf)+(p2 -> coEf)), p1 -> expnt, NULL);
        p2 = p2 -> next;
        p1 = p1 -> next;
    }
    if( p1 -> expnt > p2 -> expnt)
    {
        pt = get_node( p1 -> coEf, p1 -> expnt, NULL);
        p1 = p1 -> next;
    }
    if( p1 -> expnt < p2 -> expnt)
    {
        pt = get_node( p2 -> coEf, p2 -> expnt, NULL);
        p2 = p2 -> next;
    }
    else
    {
        pt = get_node( 1, 2, NULL);
    }
return temp;    
}

// main.cpp 
// function that calls the class member function operator +( Poly source)
void addPoly()
{
int add1;
int add2;         
int add3;
cout << "Enter the name of two polynomials to add them: " << endl;
cin >> add1 >> add2;
cout << "Enter a name for the new added polynomial: " << endl; 
cin >> add3;
pList[add3] = pList[add1] + pList[add2];

}
```

Comment: I think you mean `Node*& pt = temp.first;`, so each modification of `pt` will modify `temp` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problems:**

The problem is that you don't put anything in `temp`.

Nothing happens when you write:

```
Poly temp;     // create an default initialized Poly 
Node* pt = temp.first;   // this is a local variable.  You just copy a pointer to a node

...

if(first==NULL)
{
    Poly(source);    // You create an object but don't store nor return anything!! 
}
```

Later you store a `get_note()` in pt, which modifies only the local pointer variable. The original value that was pointed to is not changed, and so it has no impact on `temp` !

When you assign p1 and p2 to their next element, you face a similar issue:  it has only an effect on a local variable and will have no effect on your poly.

By the way, if you try to add polynoms, please note that you only handle here the first term and you do not properly process the remaining ones.

**Way to a solution:**

For your first return:

```
if(first==NULL)
{
    return source;   // You have return by value, so source will be copied  
}
```

Then before you `return temp;`, add this statement:

```
temp.first = pt;
```

And if you'r adding polynoms, you should consider creating a loop to process not only the first terms, but also the remaining ones.

Comment: @mosmic12: `pt` is not an alias of `temp.first` but a copy of it (which is overwritten later).

Comment: @mosmic12 No, even if it was, you define it as a pointer variable in the scope of `Poly::operator+()`.

Comment: @Christophe Yes, good call on the remaining loop that needs to be made, I had that in mind but I needed to make this work first. Also would it be correct to say that I was storing a value each for `coEf` , `expnt` , and `next` but only in a node somewhere in the memory and there was no connection between that node and a way to access it in the program? So in doing that line of code we create a pointer whose sole job is to point to that node? I tried it and worked! Thank you